# Dropout on test somehow causes LSTM performance failure

Tags: tensorflow

I have a problem with TensorFlow where the performance of my LSTM drops dramatically (from 70% to <10%) when I use input dropout.

As I understand it I should set the input_keep_probability to (e.g.) 0.5 during training and then to 1 during testing. This makes perfect sense, but I cant get it to work as intended. If I set the dropout during testing the same as during training my performance improves (this is not the case in the example below, but this needs less code and the point is the same).

[The accuracy and cost of 3 runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKbsU.png)

The 'best' line is no dropout, the worst line is [keep_prob@train: 0.5, keep_prob@test: 1] and the center line is [keep_prob@train: 0.5, keep_prob@test: 0.5]. These are cost and accuracy on the test set. They all behave as expected on the train set.

Below is the code that I think is essential. Sadly I cant post the full code or a data sample due to its sensitive nature, but please comment if you need more info.

```
lstm_size = 512
numLayers = 4
numSteps = 15

lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(lstm_size, state_is_tuple=True, forget_bias=1)
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, input_keep_prob=input_keep_prob)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * numLayers, state_is_tuple=True)

_inputs = [tf.squeeze(s, [1]) for s in tf.split(1, numSteps, input_data)]
(outputs, state) = rnn.rnn(cell, _inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs = tf.pack(outputs)

#transpose so I can put all timesteps through the softmax at once
outputsTranspose = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, lstm_size])

softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [lstm_size, nof_classes])                         
softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [nof_classes]) 

logits = tf.matmul(outputsTranspose, softmax_w) + softmax_b

loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, targets)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

targetPrediction = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(targetPrediction, targets), "float"))

"""Optimizer"""
with tf.name_scope("Optimizer") as scope:
    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()

    #We clip the gradients to prevent explosion
    grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cost, tvars),maxGradNorm)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    gradients = zip(grads, tvars)
    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op);

    for i in range(nofBatches * nofEpochs):
        example_batch, label_batch = sess.run(readTrainDataOp)

        result = sess.run([train_op, accuracy, trainSummaries], feed_dict = {input_data: example_batch, targets: label_batch, input_keep_prob:trainInputKeepProbability, batch_size_ph:batch_size})
        #logging

        if i % 50 == 0:
            runTestSet()
            #relevant part of runTestSet(): 
            #result = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict = {input_data: testData, targets: testLabels, input_keep_prob:testInputKeepProbability, batch_size_ph:testBatchSize})
            #logging
```

What am I doing wrong that creates this unexpected behaviour?

EDIT: <s>Here is an image of what an input sample looks like</s> See next link.

The problem also presists with only 1 layer.

EDIT: [I made an example that reproduces the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v68530h790vfk2c/AAAWZ7EsDIVF8dZ87h41-3ipa?dl=0). Just run the python script with the path to test_samples.npy as first argument and the path to the checkpoint as second argument.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem with a small amount of code and some test data that you can share? That would help us debug the problem more effectively.

Comment: this is pretty short

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I disabled my notifications by mistake. I have added an image of the input to the question. I will also write a bit of code to read a checkpoint and run tests with and without dropout on a few test samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try input_keep_prob = output_keep_prob = 0.7 for training 
and 1.0 keep prob for testing

0.5 keep prob doesn't work well om my LSTM either

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I disabled my notifications by mistake. It is running now with the parameters you suggested and it is doing the same thing again. My best result so far is actually input_keep_prob = 0.8 for the first layer and 0.5 for the next 3 layers and [0.8, 1, 1, 1] for testing (80% accuracy). If I run my testset with all keep_probs at 1.0 (with the same weights) the result drops to 10-15% or so.